# How to display dropdown items below of the control placed in screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I designed a form having two dropdowns.Based on first dropdown selection,second dropdown items are loading.But second dropdown having 100'of records.It's occupying so much space in IE.But in mozilla the items are occupying less space.How to handle that styles in IE.Please let me know how to avoid the space in IE.Based on space avilable in IE dropdowns items are occupying the whole space.

EDIT :

```
.dropmenu {

        width: 250px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;     
    }
  .dropmenu:focus {
  position:relative; 
  }

 <td>
          <span id="filterApp"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByName", new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedApplication.Name), "ALL",new { @class = "dropmenu" })%></span>
        </td>
        <td>
         Role
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="filterRole"><%= Html.DropDownList("filterByRole", new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedRole.Name), "ALL", new { @class = "dropmenu" })%></span>
        </td>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Show your code.Do you want us to guess what your code is?Sorry i cant

Comment: if roles having 100's of records so that it's occupying the more space in IE.in mozilla it's looking good.In IE only the items are crossing the browser .